# How to solve "AttributeError: module 'google.protobuf.descriptor' has no attribute '_internal_create_key"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, object-detection-api, proto

I encountered it while executing `from object_detection.utils import label_map_util` in jupyter notebook. It is actually the tensorflow object detection tutorial notebook(it comes with the tensorflow object detection api)
The complete error log:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-7035655b948a> in <module>
      1 from object_detection.utils import ops as utils_ops
----> 2 from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
      3 from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py in <module>
     25 import tensorflow as tf
     26 from google.protobuf import text_format
---> 27 from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
     28 
     29 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\object_detection\protos\string_int_label_map_pb2.py in <module>
     19   syntax='proto2',
     20   serialized_options=None,
---> 21   create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,
     22   serialized_pb=b'\n2object_detection/protos/string_int_label_map.proto\x12\x17object_detection.protos\"\xc0\x01\n\x15StringIntLabelMapItem\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\n\n\x02id\x18\x02 \x01(\x05\x12\x14\n\x0c\x64isplay_name\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12M\n\tkeypoints\x18\x04 \x03(\x0b\x32:.object_detection.protos.StringIntLabelMapItem.KeypointMap\x1a(\n\x0bKeypointMap\x12\n\n\x02id\x18\x01 \x01(\x05\x12\r\n\x05label\x18\x02 \x01(\t\"Q\n\x11StringIntLabelMap\x12<\n\x04item\x18\x01 \x03(\x0b\x32..object_detection.protos.StringIntLabelMapItem'
     23 )

AttributeError: module 'google.protobuf.descriptor' has no attribute '_internal_create_key'
```

Answer (score 197, accepted):

The protoc version I got through `pip show protobuf` and `protoc --version` were different. The version in pip was a bit outdated.

After I upgraded the pip version with

```sh
pip install --upgrade protobuf
```

the problem was solved.

Comment: If python3, use `pip3 install --upgrade protobuf`.

Comment: Not working any more.

Comment: I got this to work (on Ubuntu) with: `pip install --upgrade pip` --> `pip install --upgrade protobuf` - and not sure how to show as multi-line comment here, hence the -->

Answer (score 50):

These three commands solved it for me:

```sh
pip uninstall protobuf python3-protobuf
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade protobuf
```

Comment: In my case, I only had to upgrade pip and and protobuf (within the virtual environment) from `3.11.3` to `3.13.0`

Comment: Simply updating protobuf from 3.11.2 to 3.13.0 was sufficient for me.

Comment: It also works for me. Although I upgraded protobuf, it did not work. Then I run the following comment `pip uninstall protobuf python3-protobuf` and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This can be due to incorrect versions of protobuf and python3-protobuf in your IDE(in my case PyCharm) and in site-packages. Following solved error in my case:

```
pip uninstall python3-protobuf
pip uninstall protobuf
```

then finally do

```
pip install protobuf
```

Also if you have requirements.txt or setup.py check protobuf version from pip freeze and use the same version in your requirements.txt file

```
pip freeze
```

(check protobuf version, and use same in requirements.txt)

`protobuf==3.15.6` (in my case pip freeze gave me this version for protobuf)

Answer (score 3):

For others looking into this more recently newer google libraries are using proto plus, a wrapper for python proto messages. Using this helper function worked for me (cred: tobked)

```
import json

import proto

def proto_message_to_dict(message: proto.Message) -> dict:
    """Helper method to parse protobuf message to dictionary."""
    return json.loads(message.__class__.to_json(message))
```

https://github.com/googleapis/python-memcache/issues/19

Answer (score 2):

After trying many different solutions (i'm working on a Mac) the one that worked for me is to reinstall protobuf using:

```
PROTOC_ZIP=protoc-3.7.1-osx-x86_64.zip
curl -OL https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.7.1/$PROTOC_ZIP
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local bin/protoc
sudo unzip -o $PROTOC_ZIP -d /usr/local 'include/*'
rm -f $PROTOC_ZIP
```

As is highlighted in [this article](http://google.github.io/proto-lens/installing-protoc.html)

Answer (score 2):

the problem for me was i had `libprotobuf` at `3.11` and `protobuf` at `3.15` upgrading libprotobuf fixed it for me.

Comment: There is no package called `libprotobuf` on pypi?

Comment: I think it's on anaconda, I didn't explicitly install it I think it had gotten installed as a dependency of something else.

Comment: This worked for me. Specifically, by doing `conda install -c conda-forge libprotobuf=3.15`. I had to specify the version and upgrade it.

Answer (score 2):

I got this problem in Anaconda too.
I installed it with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge streamlit
```

with the versions `protobuf` and `libprotobuf` of 3.11.4

I was not able to update neither `protobuf` nor `libprotobuf`.

I recommend to install first "conda install protobuf" and then

```
conda install -c conda-forge streamlit
```

I got now the versions `protobuf` and `libprotobuf` of 3.14.0 and it works.

Answer (score 2):

The issue of my condition is `protoc` not install.

step to solve the problem:

1. check `pip3 show protobuf`, you will see version of `protobuf`.

   - e.q. `Version: 3.17.3`
2. goto [protobuf release page](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases) and install same version of `protoc`

   - e.q.

     1. `wget https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v3.17.3/protoc-3.17.3-linux-x86_64.zip`
     2. `unzip protoc-3.17.3-linux-x86_64.zip`
     3. `vim ~/.bashprofile` and paste `PATH=$PATH:/home/YOUR_HOST_NAME/bin`
     4. `source ~/.bashprofile` and `echo $PATH` to check whether `/home/YOUR_HOST_NAME/bin` exist or not.
3. check `pip3 show protobuf` is equal to `protoc --version`
4. If not work, reboot and try again.

Answer (score 1):

#### Downgrade protobuf using pip

Sometimes the upgrade code `pip install --upgrade protobuf` throwed another error. -

- version 3.20 seems to be working properly

```
pip install protobuf==3.20.*
```

similar to [TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441758/typeerror-descriptors-cannot-not-be-created-directly)

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you use protoc to generate your language specific bindings file in a different OS than where you import it. For example,

Linux OS

```
protoc -I=./ --python_out=./ my_module.proto
```

Mac OS

```
import my_module_pb2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was passing a dictionary to where the Google cloud API was expecting a string. Woops.