# 'google.protobuf.descriptor' has no attribute '_internal_create_key'

Tags: python, linux, protocol-buffers, simpletransformers

I get the following error when trying to import `simpletransformers`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "...py", line 106, in <module>

    from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel, ClassificationArgs

  File "/home/work/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simpletransformers/classification/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    from simpletransformers.classification.classification_model import ClassificationModel

  File "/home/work/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simpletransformers/classification/classification_model.py", line 32, in <module>

    from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter

  File "/home/work/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>

    from .record_writer import RecordWriter

  File "/home/work/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboardX/record_writer.py", line 18, in <module>

    from google.cloud import storage

  File "/home/work/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>

    from google.cloud.storage.batch import Batch

  File "/home/work/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/batch.py", line 29, in <module>

    from google.cloud import _helpers

  File "/home/work/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 33, in <module>

    from google.protobuf import duration_pb2

  File "/home/work/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/protobuf/duration_pb2.py", line 21, in <module>

    create_key=_descriptor._internal_create_key,

AttributeError: module 'google.protobuf.descriptor' has no attribute '_internal_create_key'
```

I already tried upgrading `protobuf` and have same `protoc` version like in this question:
[How to solve "AttributeError: module 'google.protobuf.descriptor' has no attribute '_internal_create_key"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922334/how-to-solve-attributeerror-module-google-protobuf-descriptor-has-no-attribu)

I also tried upgrading other packages. What else could be the problem?

I am having the issue on cloud linux machine. On my local windows machine, there is no problem.

Answer (score 3):

The protoc version I got through pip show protobuf and protoc --version were different. The version in pip was a bit outdated.

After I upgraded the pip version with

```
pip install --upgrade protobuf
```

the problem was solved.

If python3, use `pip3 install --upgrade protobuf`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue of `protobuf` version is equal to `protoc` and error still exist. But after rebooting my computer, It's work.