# Getting AttributeError: module 'proto' has no attribute 'module'

Tags: python, docker, pip, google-cloud-run, proto

I'm trying to deploy a gRPC server to Cloud Run using Docker to create associated image. I am getting the following error when called:

```
[] Traceback (most recent call last):
      > []   File "server.py", line 5, in <module>
      > []     from servicers import PredictionServiceServicer
      > []   File "/src/servicers.py", line 5, in <module>
      > []     import google.cloud.logging
      > []   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
      > []     from google.cloud.logging_v2 import __version__
      > []   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
      > []     from google.cloud.logging_v2.client import Client
      > []   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/client.py", line 22, in <module>
      > []     from google.cloud.logging_v2 import _gapic
      > []   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/_gapic.py", line 18, in <module>
      > []     from google.cloud.logging_v2.services.config_service_v2 import ConfigServiceV2Client
      > []   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/services/config_service_v2/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
      > []     from .client import ConfigServiceV2Client
      > []   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/services/config_service_v2/client.py", line 35, in <module>
      > []     from google.cloud.logging_v2.services.config_service_v2 import pagers
      > []   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/services/config_service_v2/pagers.py", line 27, in <module>
      > []     from google.cloud.logging_v2.types import logging_config
      > []   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/types/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
      > []     from .log_entry import (
      > []   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/logging_v2/types/log_entry.py", line 26, in <module>
      > []     __protobuf__ = proto.module(
      > [] AttributeError: module 'proto' has no attribute 'module'
 - deployment/****-service failed. Error: container *******-service-container terminated with exit code 1.
Cleaning up...
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.6.8-slim
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3 python3-pip -y

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
    
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip

ENV PORT 8080

COPY . ./

ENV PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION "cpp"
    
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
    
WORKDIR "/src"

EXPOSE 50051

CMD ["python3", "server.py"]
```

with requirements.txt being:

```
argparse
proto-plus 
grpcio 
grpcio-tools
google-cloud-logging #==1.15.1
google-cloud-datastore #==1.15.3
google-cloud-bigquery #==1.14.0
```

Though I have been playing around with different variations of base image and pip/pip3 imstalls of protobuf etc so any suggestions are welcome. Also when i run:

```
pip3 uninstall protobuf
```

I get three options. Deleted 3.19.1 but still getting error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/protobuf/*
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/protobuf-3.19.1-py3.8-nspkg.pth
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/protobuf-3.19.1.dist-info/*
```

Comment: Additional info: when i downgrade google-cloud package < v2.0.0 it works but obviously that's not a solution as v2 google-cloud packages are required.

Answer (score 0):

I found these similar issues that were caused by using different versions of protobuf and protoc. [The first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66596411/google-protobuf-descriptor-has-no-attribute-internal-create-key) and [the second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922334/how-to-solve-attributeerror-module-google-protobuf-descriptor-has-no-attribu)  cases suggest running this command:

> ```
>   pip3 install --upgrade protobuf
> ```

[Another case](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/issues/87) in Github issues suggest downloading certain modules as you already did and get rid of the issue; but as you said, this was not a solution for the usage of certain modules of the latest version.

And, there is the [last case](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/9409) where the protobuf module was causing issues with “MutableMapping” and was solved by changing the imports. I’m not really sure if this could also be the  case here, but I am adding it because it might be useful. It would be of great help if you could provide feedback on trying to follow this troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Alex. Will try them out and let you know.

Comment: Sure, please provide feedback on the results!

Comment: Sorry. None of the above helped. I ended up starting from scratch on gcp cloud editor for a clean environment and everything worked. I assume I have a package version issue on my local machine but will try to diagnose when I have the time. Sorry, no resolution.