# Tensorflow 1.14, Fix : "google.protobuf.message.DecodeError": Error parsing message

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers, mobilenet

Protobuf v3.15 Error: google.protobuf.message.DecodeError, When using tf.graph(), loading TensorFlow model into memory. After changing tf.graph() snippet above into TensorFlow v2, same error was getting.

I have tried protobuf 3.12.4(same on colabs), same error appeared

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/webcam.py", line 25, in <module>
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
```

I have reinstalled different protobuf version and still same error is getting.

I have trained a "SSD MobileNet" model using TensorFlow version 1.14 CPU for Webcam Object-detection with OpenCV. After installing required libraries of TensorFlow, I run model_builder_tf1.py and it successfully passed all 21 tests.

Snippet:  to load TensorFlow model into memory using tf.graph()

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
    sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph)
```

Note that TensorFlow 1.14 is installed on conda environment.

Using protobuf==3.8, another of error appeared

`AttributeError: module 'google.protobuf.descriptor' has no attribute '_internal_create_key`

Can someone please give a solution to this problem.

Comment: Could you please look at this similar issue .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922334/how-to-solve-attributeerror-module-google-protobuf-descriptor-has-no-attribu